# Swift: Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: swift, segmentation-fault

Do you guys know how to fix this error?

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

This is the function where the error appears, in get call:

```
 public var maxConcurrentOperationCount : Int {
    get {
        assert(queue != nil, "Você deve implementar o método setupQueue: antes de obter o maxConcurrentOperationCount")

        return queue!.maxConcurrentOperationCount
    }
    set {
        assert(queue != nil, "Você deve implementar o método setupQueue: antes de mudar o maxConcurrentOperationCount")

        queue?.maxConcurrentOperationCount = newValue
    }
}
```

I cant see where the problem is, cause in another project with the same code is building fine. And I've already tried the other questions here in SO about this same error and nothing happens.

I'm using Swift 4.1

***EDIT**

This is the declaration of `queue`:

```
  //MARK: - Queue
fileprivate(set) public var queue: OperationQueue? {
    get {
        return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &queueAssociationKey) as? OperationQueue
    }
    set(newValue) {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &queueAssociationKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    }
}
```

Here is my project:
https://github.com/luangs7/TodoRealm

Comment: What is the declaration of queue like? Is it optional?

Comment: Yes, @Callam. I`ll edit my question with queue declaration

Comment: Can't reproduce, copy and paste into the question as much of the swift file as possible

Comment: @Callam look at my edit question, I`ve uploaded to my github

Comment: I’ve downloaded your project, and it will compile if you simply change the name of `maxConcurrentOperationCount`. I simply added an `s` on the end of the name declaration and then it compiled. 

`public var maxConcurrentOperationCounts : Int { }`

Could it be that one of the compiled libraries you’re using also adds a property named maxConcurrentOperationCount to NSObject via an extension? Weird that it would show up as a segmentation fault, but I can't think of another explanation.

Comment: @PeteMorris thanks! As you said, after changed the name of `maxConcurrentOperationCount` it compiled. I dont undestand why another project with the same libraries and everything exacly the same doesnt appear that error